# Update Teams API documentation to reflect dependency on tier

Tags: feature-request, api, documentation, stack-overflow-for-teams

The [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/teams) says (emphasis mine):

> Starting with [the release of Stack Overflow For Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams), the Stack Exchange API exposes **read-only access** to data stored in private Teams.

This is slightly outdated; according to [this answer](https://stackapps.com/a/9311/34061), the type of access depends on the Teams tier. Could that information be added to that documentation page?